# Text slow to display after been hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I've modified the code from w3schools - [Hide paragraph](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide_slow) to include a show button which takes 6 seconds for the text to show. It takes approx 3 seconds for the text to begin re-displaying after it has been hidden, is there a reason for this ? Here is my modified code (just paste this code into "Hide paragraph" URL on w3schools) :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(3000);
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show(6000);
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button id = "hide">Hide</button>
<button id = "show">Show</button>
<p>This is a paragraph with little content.</p>
<p>This is another small paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/vWLv3/

Comment: i think the question is about why it takes so long to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's related to the easing you use. try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("p").hide(3000);
  });
  $("#show").click(function(){
    $("p").show(6000, 'linear');
  });
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/HhubD/

As you can read in the [doc](http://api.jquery.com/show/) show() has an easing parameter

```
 .show( [duration] [, easing] [, callback] )
```

> As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may
> be used. Easing functions specify the speed at which the animation
> progresses at different points within the animation. The only easing
> implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing,
> and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear. More easing
> functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the
> jQuery UI suite.

probably the "Swing" easing wich is the default is slow at the beginning and then it speeds up

Answer (score -1):

it's because of the `3000` and `6000` arguments to the `hide` and `show` arguments.  Those tell the methods how long the animation should last.  Try making the values lower; 1000 = 1 second.

Comment: thats not the answer to his question. He set 6000 to the show method and he asked why does it take 3 seconds to display it again !

Comment: @EvilP  It's the easing tha makes the funtion slower at the beginning

Comment: exuse me what are you trying to say ?